# How do you read a row of sql server db data from a biztalk orchestration?

Tags: sql, sql-server, biztalk, biztalk-2013

This is going to seem like a stupid question but I am just getting started with biztalk server 2013 R2 and need some help.  I have a fairly basic understanding of how the system works and was able to follow the msdn tutorial to create a biztalk app that moves a file from one folder, reads it and saves to another folder base on values in the file.

What I am really trying to do now is the following.  When I recieve a value, I use that value as a key to read data from a sql server table and transform that data into another format for saving/transporting elsewhere.

For the life of me I cannot find how to do the sql server portion of it.  I know you are supposed to install the adapter pack (done) and add a Consume Adapter Service and I have done that...but I don't figure out how to connect the orchestration to read the data from SQL.

If you someone could point me to a comprehensive tutorial or maybe even recommend a book that I could buy that would be fantastic.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WCF-SQL adapter in BizTalk for SQL Operation. If you do not see this adapter, then install it using BizTalk Server Installation ISO file Option Install Microsoft BizTalk Adapters and then install first three

Install Microsoft WCF LOB Adapter SDK

Install Microsoft BizTalk Adapter Pack

Install Microsoft BizTalk Adapter Pack (64 bit) in same order

Once its completed use the Consume Adapter Service Option to add necessary schemas from SQL. The Consume Adapter Service is available when you right click on project=>add generated items.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150632.aspx

Choose the options as shown in attached image, you can change your database name and tables as per yours.

[image]

Comment: I did that already but I am not sure how to configure the orchestration...

Comment: You can download samples from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=22455. After download and unzip, it contains BizTalk Server samples in BizTalk Server folder. Use the SelectTable sample from here

Answer (score 0):

You can do the SQL Adapter Tutorials which cover the topics you're asking about.

Details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788523.aspx

Answer (score 0):

So both of the above are helpful and I marked them both as answers to the question although I did find some additional information located here:

- http://vijaymstech.wordpress.com/2014/01/17/biztalk-2013-wcf-sql-adapter-select-table-operation-step-by-step/ << this blog post was very hard to read because it is mostly incomplete but it did start pointing me in the right direction of how to configure the orchestration and working form the admin console
- http://btsguru.blogspot.ca/2011/10/wcf-sql-adapter-table-operations.html  << this had some interesting information about sql operations
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/088dc2d5-b444-43a6-b1fa-aba43d720cd1/error-btsactionmapping-was-not-understood?forum=biztalkgeneral  << this post talks about the need to have the operation names be the same which also helped

Once I did seem to get it working I ran into the "The Columns are Either Duplicated or not in a Sequence" error.  I was able to fix this by copying the order of the columns in the Table.dbo.xsd schema file for the object I needed into the select operation xml columns node.

A lot of learning on this one for me so thanks for your help guys I really appreciate it!